# Trying to figure out where my touches are, when moving a slider control

Tags: iphone, uislider

I would like to create a variable speed slider control on the iPhone. 
Basically I am using a UISlider control but I would like to add a second dimension to this control by detecting where the finger is in the current view.

E.G. A user can slide the control left and right, but I want to see where their finger is vertically in the view.

My issue is that when you are manipulating a slider control.
The following function is not called.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

so this means I cannot detect any touch events because I assume they are being sent to the slider? Anyone tried to do this? Or should I sub class UISlider. Hmmm.

Comment: Hmmm looking at UISlider.h it doesn't really look like any events are sent to this class that I can catch?

Comment: here is a full tutorial of what you need http://oleb.net/blog/2011/01/obslider-a-uislider-subclass-with-variable-scrubbing-speed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface JBSlider : UISlider {
    double verticalTouchDelta;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)    double verticalTouchDelta;

@end
```

main file

## import "JBSlider.h"

@implementation JBSlider

@synthesize verticalTouchDelta;
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
    //NSLog(@"HI HI");

```
UITouch * touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
//NSLog(@"%f", [touch locationInView:self].y);
verticalTouchDelta  = [touch locationInView:self].y;
```

}

@end

Simply change your slider from UISlider to JBSlider in Interface Builder.
Works awesome.